# .NET - What is the best library for inspecting and controling Windows Services?

Tags: .net, windows-services, wmi, adsi

I need to monitor and control a set of Windows Services that are running either on a local machine or remotely. I've heard of WMI and ADSI and the first one seems to do what I want.
Before going deep into it, I just want to check if I'm going in the right direction?

Thank you

**EDIT**
Additional information: I also need to inspect SQL jobs and IIS instances so I think WMI is what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look at the `ServiceController` class.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.aspx

Comment: Interesting. However, I finally also need to inspect other elements...(see my Edit). But thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

This might help for WMI monitoring SQL job events:

http://shellyourexperience.wordpress.com/2011/08/31/monitoring-sql-server-service-with-wmi-events-and-showui/

You could also check **Win32_NTLogEvent** class:

```
wmic /namespace:\\root\cimv2 path win32_ntlogevent where SourceName='%SQL%' get /all /format:csv >"%userprofile%\desktop\wmic_win32_ntlogevent.csv"
```

However I don't think this will list specific SQL jobs. That type of action should be done in SQL itself. ADSI is Active Directory Services Interface, I don't think this what you'll need this however that will depend.